# Dummy interface for nginx

Tags: networking, vps, netplan

I have a VPS from OVH running Debian 12 that uses netplan. I have only one network interface (ens3).

Here is the only netplan config file (`/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`):

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            accept-ra: false
            addresses:
            - 2604:abcd:abcd:abcd::abcd/56
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: ab:cd:ef:11:22:33
            mtu: 1500
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 213.186.33.99
                search: []
            routes:
            -   to: ::/0
                via: 2604:abcd:abcd:abcd::1
            set-name: ens3
```

I will be using this VPS for multiple purposes and want to enforce bandwidth management using `tc`. With only one "physical" interface, I think I need to create a dummy interfaces and bind nginx to it to manage bandwidth for the web server. (Nginx can throttle per connection, but I want something to enforce max total bandwidth.)

So do I need to create a bridge, then make a dummy interface, attach ens0 and dummy0 to the bridge, and set IP addresses to br0 (public IP) and dummy0 (192.168.1.xx)? Then use IPtables to forward ports 80/443 to dummy0?

I'm pretty new to the idea of virtual networking, so your advice on what I'm trying to accomplish would be appreciated. Simplicity is favored and I'd prefer not to go the docker route. Thanks!

PS Apparently netplan got the ability to create dummy interfaces [in v. 107](https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1774203/comments/9), but I have v. 106. It can't just be easy now, can it... :)

```
# apt policy netplan.io
netplan.io:
  Installed: 0.106-2+deb12u1
  Candidate: 0.106-2+deb12u1
  Version table:
 *** 0.106-2+deb12u1 500
        500 mirror+file:/etc/apt/mirrors/debian.list bookworm/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: For my solution to bandwidth management using only a single interface, see https://serverfault.com/a/1155890/259856. No need for dummy interfaces or any virtual networking!